# How to fix undercounting cases in this java problem hw (USACO silver)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

I stumbled upon a USACO problem I can't seem to solve, and it seems that for every case I get wrong, my program always seems to undercount the number of solutions. The problem statement is here (http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=714), but I can provide a shorter version of it

Basically you're given a number of chickens and cows (n<= 20000), where each chicken has an int value x_n, and each cow has int values of a_n and b_n (they don't have to be distinct)
You want to find the maximum amount of chicken-cow pairs, where a pair is defined by:
a_n <= x_n <= b_n. Once a chicken or cow is paired, they can't pair with anyone else

How did I go wrong?

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pqChicken = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    PriorityQueue<State> pqCow = new PriorityQueue<State>();

    //read in info for chicken and cow pq (not shown)

    int ret = 0; //to record number of pairs
    while (pqChicken.size() != 0 && pqCow.size() != 0) {

        int chicken = pqChicken.peek();
        State cow = pqCow.peek();
        if (chicken < cow.low) {      //all cows are above this chicken, it can't pair
            pqChicken.poll();

        } else if (chicken > cow.high) { //all chickens are above this cow, it can't pair
            pqCow.poll();

        } else {                    //it can pair, pair them and update the number of pairs
            ret++;
            pqChicken.poll();
            pqCow.poll();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ret);
```

Here is the cow class:

```
static class State implements Comparable<State> {
    int low,high;  //low, high
    public State(int low,int high) {
        this.low=low;
        this.high=high;
    }
    public int compareTo(State a) { //sort by decreasing low, then decreasing high
        if (low > a.low)
            return 1;               //I think testing a case for equality won't matter
        if (low == a.low && high > a.high)
            return 1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What Error did you get?

Comment: All my errors are wrong answers (always lower than the correct), I feel like theres something wrong with the algorithm